# preventing parseJSON data from displaying at once. Can I make section display on next?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

var jsonp = '[{"Question":"1: Is the contract active and primary?", "Answer":"Yes","Answer2":"No","Answer3":"I dont know"},{"Question":"2: What city were you born in?","Answer":"Penn","Answer2":"New York","Answer3":"Mt Peliar"},{"Question":"3: What city were you born in?","Answer":"Penn","Answer2":"New York","Answer3":"Mt Peliar"}]';

var sName = '';
    var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);
    //var obj1 = $.parseJSON(jsonp2);
    $.each(obj, function () {
        sName += '<p>';
        sName += this['Question'] + "<br/>";
        sName += '<a href="#" class="nameLink">';
        sName += this['Answer'] + "<br/>";
        sName += '</a><span style="">';
        sName += '<a href="#" class="nameLink2">';
        sName += this['Answer2'] + "<br/>";
        sName += '</a><span style="">';
        sName += '<a href="#" class="nameLink2">';
        sName += this['Answer3'] + "</span><br/>";
        sName += '</a><span style=""><br/>';
        sName += '</a><button id="1">Next</button>';
        sName += '</p>';
        sName += '</a><span style="display:inline">';

    });
    

    
    $('span').html(sName);
/*$('a').click(function (obj) {
alert("this");
$(jsonp).hide();
});
*/
 $(".nameLink").click(function(){
     alert("yes");
  //$(this).next().toggle();  
});
   $("#1").click(function(){
$(this).find('sName').html("gg");
});
    $(".1nameLink").click(function(){
     alert("No");
  //$(this).next().toggle();  
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```

I am parsing JSON data with jQuery and I am trying to make the second question only display on next button click instead on the document load. Can this be done? I know I can hide it all at once by grabbing the var and addind the hide(). I also can easily change display:none, but cannot get this to work per question and section. I want only question 1 to show. Then on next, show question 2. Any ideas? Can this be done without breaking up the var jsonp ="" string.

Comment: use the $.each() function of jquery

Comment: I am already using $.each() but its repeating

Comment: Give some css to hide the next questions

Comment: I have tried that. No luck. Can hide it but not show it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using proper if conditions, you can get what you wanted. Added a class with prefix `block_` and id with the same string. The number after the prefix is the page number we needed. Rest is simple. When a link is clicked, we use the id of the link and using it as a class name we can get the target page.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var jsonp = '[{"Question":"1: Is the contract active and primary?", "Answer":"Yes","Answer2":"No","Answer3":"I dont know"},{"Question":"2: What city were you born in?","Answer":"Penn","Answer2":"New York","Answer3":"Mt Peliar"},{"Question":"3: What city were you born in?","Answer":"Penn","Answer2":"New York","Answer3":"Mt Peliar"}]';

    var sName = '';
    var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);
    //var obj1 = $.parseJSON(jsonp2);
    $.each(obj, function (i, value) {
        var index = i + 1;
        if (i != 0) var attribute = ' style="display:none;"';
        else var attribute = ' style="display:block;"';

        sName += '<p class="questionblocks block_' + index + '"' + attribute + '>';
        sName += this['Question'] + "<br/>";
        sName += '<a href="#" class="nameLink">';
        sName += this['Answer'] + "<br/>";
        sName += '</a><span style="">';
        sName += '<a href="#" class="nameLink2">';
        sName += this['Answer2'] + "<br/>";
        sName += '</a><span style="">';
        sName += '<a href="#" class="nameLink2">';
        sName += this['Answer3'] + "</span><br/>";
        sName += '</a><span style=""><br/>';
        if (obj.length > index) sName += '</a><button class="next" id="block_' + (index + 1) + '">Next</button>';
        else sName += '</a>';
        sName += '</p>';
        sName += '</a>';

    });
    $('span').html(sName);
    $('.next').on('click', function () {
        $('.questionblocks').hide();
        $('.' + this.id).show();
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <span></span>
```

Comment: @user2557504 A `.` prefix usually represents a class selector. In this case `$('.' + this.id)` resultant of this is `$('.block_1')` if value of id of the link is `block_1`, which is the class name for the `<p>` tag I added for the purpose of page identification.

Comment: oh ok. guess I am just not use to seeing a '.'+ with something else.